# Does sampling fraction matter for McNemar's Test?

Tags: sample, mcnemar-test, finite-population

For McNemar's Test, does the sample need to be less than 1/20 of the population if the sample is without replacement? If so, can I correct for a sample that is larger than 1/20 of the population by using the finite population correction? And without a correction, will my p-value be biased away from zero?